# Strange C# DataPager with ListView issue

Tags: c#, listview, datapager

I have a page with 2 datapagers and 1 listview. I am trying to set the pagesize programatically, it works for the first page, but not any after that. If I hard code the pagesize to 12 it works fine.

The datapagers use the querystring param of 'page'. I also set the session "PerPage" to an int value such as 12,24,48 etc to control the amount shown per page but this doesn't work either. No postbacks are performed as it's all done via the ?page=3 querystring param.

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DPTop" runat="server" QueryStringField="page" PagedControlID="resultsLV"
        OnPreRender="DPTopPreRender">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField FirstPageText="&lt;&lt;" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" />
            <asp:NumericPagerField />
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField LastPageText="&gt;&gt;" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

The Listview

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="resultsLV" OnItemDataBound="resultsLV_ItemDataBound" OnPagePropertiesChanging="PagePropertiesChanging">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="result" runat="server" id="resultItem">
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Assign page size
        if (Session["PerPage"] != null && !IsPostBack)
        {
            DPTop.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Session["PerPage"]);
            DPBottom.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Session["PerPage"]);
        }
        else
        {
            DPTop.PageSize = 12;
            DPBottom.PageSize = 12;
        }
    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!ispostback)
       {
          //bind the data
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the datapager pagesize in DataPager Init event:

aspx:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" QueryStringField="pageNumber" 
                PagedControlID="lvItemList" OnPreRender="DataPager1_PreRender" OnInit="DataPager1_Init">
```

c#

```
protected void DataPager1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataPager1.PageSize = 8;
}
```